# How to apply time limit to a loop in typescript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, typescript

I have a loop looks like below.

```
let currentResult = []
for(let i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
    currentResult = someComputation(...)
    if(endingCondition) {
       break
    }
}
return currentResult
```

I want not only iteration limit, but also time limit.

I know I can use `Date.now()` to get the start time, and then check how long has passed after every iteration.

However, it will stop after it finish the current iteration, that means it will exceed the time limit a little bit.

What I want is something like `settimeout`, when the time is over, it just return the `currentResult` and abandon the ongoing iteration.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, because as it's single-threaded, if a computation takes a long time, it blocks the thread, period. I don't think you can kill it midway with another "master" instruction that would go "Eh, time's up". I'd love somebody to prove me wrong, though.

Comment: You cannot. JS is a single threaded. If your loop is taking too much time, any change to other variable will not be processed as you loop has consumed thread

Comment: You cannot externally cancel a function execution. And there is no multithreading in JavaScript unless you explicitly opt into that. You shift to async functionality but that will allow you to return when either the end condition or the time limit is reached *however*, computation would still be performed. You would just have to discard the result when `someComputation` finishes and you've already returned the previous result.

Answer (score 2):

By utilizing generator functions you can achieve functions that can be halted in the middle:

```
  function limited(time, fn) {
   return function(...args) {
     const it = fn(...args), start = Date.now();
     while(Date.now() - start < time) {
       const { value, done } = it.next();
       if(done) return { value };
     }
     return { terminated: true };
   }
 }

 const longComputation = limited(1000, function* () {
   while(true) {
     yield; // < breaking point for safe termination
   }
 });

for(let i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
  const { result, terminated } = longComputation(...);
  if(terminated) {
     break
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be even easier if you shift over the `maxIterations` as part of `limited`. So the consuming code just specifies what the maximum results would be and the time limit, then just consumes the sequence until finished.